# Hover over variable during debugging doesnt show value?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

Whilst debugging C++ in VS2012 I have inserted a break point and executed the code. When the breakpoint is reached I hover over the name of any int/string variable declared (and assigned) previous to the breakpoint but the intellisense does not show the latest value for the variable. I thought it was supposed to do this? Is there a setting which I need to enable?

Answer (score 2):

Had VS2012 set to "release" rather than "debug"